# Git Clone over SSH when Google Authenticator is in use

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys, google-authenticator

I've not found a suitable answer to this, if the ssh server in use requires Google Authenticator for 2FA, how can this be used with git (for example git clone, git push etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge you have to switch your GIT repository to HTTPS to use 2FA which will give additional personal access token on your mobile device or like that in addition to your password.

Comment: Yep. It certainly seems that way (in my recent experiments) - a deficiency it would seem

Comment: Yup! Https was the solution, unfortunately even with 2FA enabled it doesn't ask for it, but that's a different bug, I guess